# How to do geo searches on two properties as opposed to an array of [ lng, lat ]?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geo

All of the examples and implementations of geo search in Mongo, that I've been able to find, use an array property `[lng, lat]` to perform the search on:

An example record would be:

```
{
   name: 'foo bar',
   locations: [
     {
       name: 'franks house',
       geo: [-0.12, 34.51]
     },
     {
       name: 'jennifers house',
       geo: [-0.09, 32.17]
     }
   ]
}
```

And the resulting query:

```
db.events.find({ 'locations.geo': { $nearSphere: [ -0.12, 34.51 ], $maxDistance: 0.02 }})
```

This works fine, but the format of the record is not great for users to read or write because it's not self-documenting where `lat` and `lng` go in that array. There's room for gotchas. I'd like to make the records more human friendly:

```
{
   name: 'foo bar',
   locations: [
     {
       name: 'franks house',
       lat: 34.51,
       lng: -0.12
     },
     {
       name: 'jennifers house',
       lat: 32.17,
       lng: -0.09
     }
   ]
}
```

What would the resulting mongo query look like for this type of record? I haven't been able to find any examples of this so am wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: If you want to use the mongo geo operators you gave to keep the [lon, lat] format. Anyway, just a side note, usually 'users' are not supposed to directly read/write from the database (MVC?).

Comment: It's a REST API, and I need the easiest way to return JSON results. It doesn't need to be exactly like the database struct, but the less data-formatting I have to do the faster the response times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to use separate fields for latitude and longitude. The 2dsphere index is used to index geospatial data which requires an array of coordinates, see [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/). This is the reason you can't find examples for separate coordinate fields.

You should separate representation from data storage. Just because coordinates are stored in an array, you don't necessarily need to present them as an array to the user. For example you could use a pre call on save to store separate parameters in an array, something like:

```
var schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.coordinates = [this.longitude, this.latitude]
  next();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this was my second option, but I wanted to check first. Your answer is almost comprehensive, but the one issue I had with this approach was how to fetch the results and easily translate back to the user-friendly data struct. I couldn't find anything in Mongoose like `schema.post('find', ...` or something. Could you elaborate?

Comment: So, any modifications made to the doc object will be applied to all object results whenever a query is made and returned?

Comment: I can't say it for sure, but I think so. If it doesn't work, then you can use `toObject()` instead which is then passed to `JSON.stringify()`. You can find examples here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject